# call another activity after the click on the menu

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a menu and want to call the next activity , so that the user can calculate and then want to return the next page or the home page , but do not know how to do this ... Ja tried in many ways , but not the right or when it works on another page disappear all anetriores menus , leaving you stuck only that activity.

*I am new to programming and especially on android.*

**MainActivity:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            //I want to call the page " calculations" here.

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**android_manifest.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stark.hello_world">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Calculos"
            android:label="@string/action_help"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**calculos.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ff0fffab">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="SEM"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_3_material"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: app]

Comment: Question is unclear. Simply calling an activity is pretty much basic so I suppose that its not what you are asking. You need to clarify what is meat by "...and then want to return the next page or the home page.." .

Comment: @MalithLakshan 
Yes , I'm sorry for the lack of clarity, what I want is to click on a menu item and be directed to the page or activity correspondent, this is not happening and I do not know how to do, although reading about it in several places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question but I guess you want to open a new Activity after a menu item was clicked?

For this you need to start an Intent in your if - I've added the line you need to your code

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        //I want to call the page " calculations" here.
        //with this code you can call a new activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        //create another Intent here and navigate to the correct activity
}
```

But I would suggest to use Fragments instead of Activities and use `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(YourFragment.newInstance());`

Answer (score 1):

set the parent activity to your android_manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Help"
        android:label="@string/action_help"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: changed the manifest of the stretch but still does not call the calculus of the page when I click on " calculations " on the side menu , you need to make any more changes ? the code for example?

Comment: oh im not too sure about that sorry @PauloRoberto